# Enable bluetooth on ASUS ROG Strix B460-F?

Tags: motherboard, bluetooth

On the [product page for this motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B460-F-GAMING/) ASUS says that Bluetooth 5.1 will be supported as of Windows 10 build 19041:

[image: Screenshot of product page]

According to the `winver` utility, my Windows build is `19041.388`:

[image]

But in my Windows system settings for bluetooth, I'm missing the "enable Bluetooth" switch:

[image]

[image]

I also can't find any Bluetooth devices in Device Manager (I tried turning on "Show hidden devices").

And I cannot find any Bluetooth drivers available on [ASUS support page for this product](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B460-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/).

Can someone please tell me how I'm supposed to enable Bluetooth? Or is ASUS just lying about Bluetooth support here?

Comment: Have you contacted Asus support?

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time a company claimed something would be ready by X date and wasn't.

Comment: Is your bluetooth services running under `services.msc`?

Comment: Have you re-checked the page recently?  I just went on there and did not find any mention of bluetooth anywhere on the product's splash page, nor the technical specifications page.  I tried looking under M.2 section, all it mentions is that the wifi module is sold separately.  Also, just in case, try and see if you can find bluetooth drivers from [MoKiChU](https://rog.asus.com/forum/search.php?searchid=8729139) in the ROG forums or PM him for help.